# Can anonymous union be declared as constexpr in C++?

Tags: c++, static, language-lawyer, constexpr, unions

I shall admit that the question below might be not very much practical, but still it would be nice to find the answer.

In C++ one can declare a `constexpr` unnamed `union` that simultaneously defines variable `u` at global scope:

```
constexpr static union {
    int i = 1;
} u; //ok everywhere
```

Static anonymous unions are also permitted:

```
static union {
    int j = 1;
}; //ok everywhere
```

But can anonymous union be declared as constexpr?

```
constexpr static union {
    int k = 1;
}; //ok in GCC only
```

GCC does accept it as well. MSVC prints seemingly wrong error:

```
error C2737: 'k': constexpr object must be initialized
```

And the error from Clang is

```
union cannot be marked constexpr
```

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GafazTbqK

Comment: Aren't these all unnamed unions? The first case only also declares a variable of that type, no?

Comment: how is the first one different from the third one? Was the first one not supposed to be static?

Comment: @jwezorek, the first one defines variable `u` (and `u.i`); the third one is fully anonymous union, defining just `k`.

Comment: oh yeah, missed that `u` at the end there